# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir la cantidad de dígitos de un número?

Tags: c

Acudo a ustedes nuevamente ya que no encuentro forma de hacer que la linea 15 imprima correctamente el numero de dígitos que tiene el numero ingresado. Sé que con `strlen` se puede hacer, pero la única forma en la que me funciona es declarando `rut[i]` como un `char` y tiene que ser obligatoriamente `int` y también tiene que estar obligatoriamente de esta forma `rut[i]`, porque `rut` tiene que almacenarse en el arreglo para luego imprimirlo (este no es el código completo, es solo una parte).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    int i, n, datos, longi, rut[20], longitud;
    char nombre[30][30];
    for(i=0;i<1;i++)
    {
        printf("Ingrese su primer nombre: ");
        scanf("%s",nombre[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<1;i++)
    {
        printf("Ingrese el rut de %s sin digito verificador: ",nombre[i]);
        scanf("%i",&rut[i]);
        longitud=strlen(rut);
        printf("%d",longitud);
    }
}
```

Comment: Deja ver si te entendí, tu tienes en rut[i] un número ej 1234 y lo que quieres saber es la longitud de ese número que en este caso es 4?

Comment: exacto, eso mismo

Comment: Y que requisitos te pone el profesor para hacer esto

Comment: tengo que usar solo lo que este dentro de las librerias que estan puestas ahi arriba y funciones

Comment: Una duda asi rapida. Ya van 2 preguntas en las que miro que pones en tu codigo: `for(i=0;i<1;i++)`. Porque haces eso? Es lo mismo que colocarlo directamente y es menos confuso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si vamos a la documentación de [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen), veras que la función toma un `const char *`.

Recuerda que en C las cadenas de caracteres son de la siguiente forma:

```
| c | c | c | c | c | \0 |
```

Siendo c un caracter random.

Lo que hará `strlen` será ir a la dirección de memoria que le diste, y va a leer hasta llegar a un `\0`.

Si quieres contar los dígitos utilizando `stlen`, puedes pasar el numero a un `char[]` primero. Puedes "imprimirlo" usando [`sprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STR_INT_SIZE 11

int main() {
    int i = 0; // Puedes hacer for (int i=0; ...) y es mas claro.
    int n = 0;
    int datos = 0;
    int longi = 0; 
    int rut[20]; // Porque 20, que significa?
    size_t longitud = 0; // Tiene que ser un site_t, no un entero.
    char nombre[30][30]; // Porque 30, que significa?
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        printf("Ingrese su primer nombre: ");
        scanf("%s", nombre[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        printf("Ingrese el rut de %s sin digito verificador: ", nombre[i]);
        scanf("%i", &rut[i]);
        char str_rut[MAX_STR_INT_SIZE + 1];
        sprintf(str_rut, "%d", rut[i]);
        longitud = strlen(str_rut);
        printf("%zu", longitud);
    }
}
```

#### Notas

- Procura no tener números mágicos en tu código. Es preferible que uses constantes como `MAX_STR_INT_SIZE`. Así se entiende el propósito del numero, y tienes mas fácil hacer cambios

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez mi respuesta no resuelva tu problema (por los requisitos de tu profesor), sin embargo, puede que a otra persona si le sirva.

> > ¿Cómo puedo imprimir la cantidad de dígitos de un número?

Puedes contar la cantidad de dígitos de un número con la función [log10](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/log10/) (está declarada en la cabecera `math.h`).

El valor que reciba el parámetro de la función `log10` debe ser un número mayor a `0` (así funciona los [logaritmos](https://logaritmo.org/logaritmo-de-0)), por lo tanto, esta restricción la debemos tomar en cuenta en nuestra implementación:

```c
int contarDigitos(int x)
{
    //Si es 0, le incrementamos un 1.
    if(x == 0)
        ++x;
    //Si es numero negativo, lo convertimos a un numero positivo.
    else if(x < 0)
        x = -x;
    return (int)log10(x) + 1;
}
```

**Uso:**

```c
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", contarDigitos(0));
    printf("%d\n", contarDigitos(-1));
    printf("%d\n", contarDigitos(-1000));
    printf("%d\n", contarDigitos(20));
    printf("%d\n", contarDigitos(50000));
    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en este enlace: https://onlinegdb.com/BJLstjaYw

Comment: No es estrictamente "*según la documentación*", sino una propiedad matemática: no hay *ningún* número al que puedas elevar a 10 y te de 0.

Answer (score 1):

Bien al ver los requisitos con los que tienes que cumplir te propongo un método básico pero efectivo:

```
if(rut[i] >= 0 && rut[i] < 10)
{
   //imprimo un dígito 
}
else if(rut[i] >= 10 && rut[i] < 100)
{
   //imprimo dos dígitos
}
else if(rut[i] >= 100 && rut[i] < 1000)
{
   //imprimo tres dígitos
}
```

Y así sucesivamente:

La idea es sencilla la primera condición se cumple si un número está entre **0** y **9** de ser cierto la longitud es **1**.

La segunda condición se cumple si un número está entre **10** y **99** de ser cierto la longitud es **2**, y así sucesivamente se va comprobando el número por los rangos que me interesan.

Comment: Aunque ya tienes otra respuesta, te recomiendo por favor que analices la solución que te propongo, también puede serte util

Comment: Aquí sí que no se usa ninguna libreria

Comment: Hombre, esa lleva mucho copy paste va? Y si pruebas meterla en un for? Asi te ahorras el copiar y pegar haciendo modificaciones pequeñas.

Comment: pablohaches, antes de responder esta pregunta le pregunte al usuario los requisitos que pedia el profesor, el cual era no usar ninguna funcion de las librerias de c, eso fue lo que yo hice darle una respuesta sin usar ninguna de las funciones de c, en cuanto a las modificaciones que propones pues que las pida el usuario

Comment: no tengo nada en contra de tu respuesta pablohaches pero veo que tu usas strlen, y eso fue una de las cosas que el pidio, no usar ninguna funcion

Comment: Hombre, yo tampoco tengo nada en contra de la tuya, solo son sujerencias que nos hacemos entre nostros. En eso se basa el sitio, no en competencia, sino en compartir conocimeinto. Igual si fuera competencia nos gano Mrdave. Yo decia porque lo miraba mas simple, y cumple con la regrla DRY. Entre sus librerias esta `string.h` por eso supuse que podia usar strlen.

Comment: No amigo yo no estoy echando competencia, simplemente trataba de esclarecer,  tu sabes que muchas veces los usuarios no saben lo que quieren y más si son principiantes,  te doy mi voto positivo

Comment: Bueno es cierto. Igualmente te deje yo el mio. Mucha suerte